# Derivatives and their implications

Tags: functions, derivatives

So I have this question ( i am not interested in the nash equilibrium result).

[image]

and I want to understand how  *x* and *y* change according different values.

So i find the derivative of *f(x,y)* with respect to x, equate it to 0, to find that the value of *y= 2/3.*

I then find the derivative of *g(x,y)* with respect to y , equate it to 0, to find the value of *x= 1/2.*

On the answer sheet it states that:
[image]

And this is the thing I do not understand.

*x=1* if *y* is greater than 2/3.

*x=0* if *y* is smaller than 2/3.

Same thing counts for *y*.

*y=0* if *x* is greater than *1/2*, and *y=1* if *x* is smaller than 1/2.

Can somebody please explain in the simplest way possible how to get to these results? Please make it as clear and simple as possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to maximize $f(x,y)|_{y=y_0}$
You know that if $y_0=\frac{2}{3}, \ \  f(x,y_0)=0$, $\ \ $so it doesn't matter what value of $x$ you pick,
 $f(x,\frac{2}{3})=0$ always.
If $y_0>\frac{2}{3}$, for instance let consider $y_0=1$, $\ \ $$f(x,1)=x+2 \ \ $ which gets maximized by
$x=1 \ \ ,$ ( remember that $x\in [0,1]$).
If $y_0<\frac{2}{3}$, for instance let consider $y_0=0$, $\ \ $$f(x,1)=1-2x \ \ $ which gets maximized by $x=0$.

The same reasoning happens with $g(x,y)$ .

Comment: How do i know when a function gets maximised when x=1?

Comment: can i find the result for example for the best reponse 1 if i plug x=1 in the original equation and see that y=4, hence its greater than 2/3?

Comment: When you have $g(x,y)$, we have that its value is $0$ when $x=\frac{1}{2}$. When $x$ is greater, for example $x=1$, $g(1,y)=-2y-1$, and you know $y\in [0,1]$. For which value of $y \ $ you get maximized $g(1,y)$? For the value of $y\in [0,1]$ which maximizes $-2y-1$. This is a linear function and so is really simple to maximize: if $y=0 \implies g(1,0)=-1$, while if $y=1 \implies g(1,1)=-3$. If you pick any value of $y\in (0,1)$, $g(1,y)\in (-3,-1)$. Then... what value of $y$ makes $g(1,y)$  greater? $y=0$. A lineal function always gets its maximum on one of the extremes.

Comment: No, you cannont do that. In this case you would get the correct answer because the functions with a fixed parameter are linear, but if they were quadratic for example it would not work. If you want to know how to maximize a function with $1$ variable (or more than one, but all fixed except one), you derivate with respect to that variable, look on which points its derivate equals $0$ and these points are candidates of a global maximum. Then you calculate the value of the function on those points AND on the extreme points (the border points), and you get the one that gives you the maximum.